# .NET Framework 4.8 Environment.UserInteractive always returns true regardless if it was started in a service or not

Tags: c#, .net, service, .net-4.8

I'm writing a program that can be ran as both a console app and as a service. Right now, it's basically:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        // Console App
        // contains code that causes an error when ran as a service
    }
    else
    {
        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new HostManagerService(logger)
        };

        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

However, the Environment.UserInteractive always returns true. I know that this is true because when I try to run the program as a service, I run into an error because this runs the console app version of the code instead of the service version. Does anyone know why this could be the case?

EDIT: To run it as a service, I find the .exe file and run, "myprogram.exe -i" in my command prompt to install the .exe as a service and then in the Services window, I right click and press start (with Allow service to interact with desktop disabled).

Comment: Can you elaborate, what do you do to "run it as service"

Comment: @T.S. apologies, should have clarified. To run it as a service, I find the .exe file and run, "myprogram.exe -i" in my command prompt to install the .exe as a service and then in the Services window, I right click and press start (with Allow service to interact with desktop disabled). I am not sure why this is not running it as a service and is still running as a console.

Comment: I think, to run application as service it must derive from a service base. If it derives from the service base, it can't be console, right?

Comment: Pretty sure that `.UserInteractive` checks for WSF_VISIBLE. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services#using-an-interactive-service Maybe your service has been started with flag `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS` ?

Comment: If you want to know if your program is actually running as a service, don't do it that way. You can see how dotnet core checks here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2d6cc77b9ea17c18e9bc6d6197d460b50c27e792/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L47

Comment: @T.S. the functions within the else block (the service) utilizes a partial service class that implements the ServiceBase class.